# How to remove XML attribute when building a WSDL/SVC service

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, soap, xml-serialization

my svc service looks like this:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://my.service.com/rem")]
[XmlSerializerFormat]
public interface IRemitTest
{
    [OperationContract]
    void Report(Block[] Block);
}
```

It wants a XML according to class send in as follows:

```
public class Block
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Pretty simple, when someone comsumes my service they should send in a soap envelope and have a array of Block with different names

My problem is when i try to send in

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:rem="http://my.service.com/rem">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <rem:Report>
            <rem:Block>
                <rem:Name>Michael Lancoln</rem:Name>
            </rem:Block>
            <rem:Block>
                <rem:Name>Luis Wholecast</rem:Name>
            </rem:Block>
            <rem:Block>
                <rem:Name>Richard Berns</rem:Name>
            </rem:Block>
        </rem:Report>
    </soapenv:Body>  
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

this does not work.. it requires

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:rem="http://my.service.com/rem">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <rem:Report>
            <rem:Block>           
                <rem:Block>
                    <rem:Name>Michael Lancoln</rem:Name>
                </rem:Block>
            </rem:Block>
            <rem:Block>           
                <rem:Block>
                    <rem:Name>Luis Wholecast</rem:Name>
                </rem:Block>
            </rem:Block>  
            <rem:Block>
                <rem:Block>
                    <rem:Name>Richard Berns</rem:Name>
                </rem:Block>
            </rem:Block>
        </rem:Report>
    </soapenv:Body>  
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

note the double rem:Block

If i change me service not to use array as input to:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://my.service.com/rem")]
[XmlSerializerFormat]
public interface IRemitTest
{
    [OperationContract]
    void Report(Block Block);
}
```

this works fine but with only one Block.. but i dont have to have double to get it in as with the array..

I have been on this for 2 days and can't figure it out how to remove the second Block

is it possible?

Any help highly appreciated :D!

Comment: It is unclear to me if you have an instance of `SoapResponses` or if you are parsing the raw xml. Could you show the part of your code that you are having a problem with?

Comment: i want basically exclude the Class name Block to be listen in the Serialized XML..

Comment: How to exclude the Report and Block that gets included automatically 
 from Report(Block[] Block)     to be excluded and just include everything in my class..

Comment: I'm sorry, I just can't understand the question.

Comment: see updated description..

Comment: When I recreate your operation contract and service it does not result in that request structure. As expected I have a "Block" element that has sequence of `Block`s so I have no idea what is going on with your system.